# How to change product page layout to 2 column left/right in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

As you can see in the title, I want to change product page layout in prestashop, for example 2 column right bar or 2 column with left bar. Is there any settings to configure this in back office or there's no such options at all? Do I have to do it through coding? Any help/guidance on this..

The purpose behind this is, I want to show category navigation in the sidebars, either left or right. It is displayed on category page by default, I want it be visible on product page as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to themes, advanced settings. The you can enable/disable columns on each page